# What data is in 'calldataload'?

Tags: solidity, events, evm, logs, calldata

I want to parse event logs that are generated by the contract shown below, which assigns different sections of **calldataload** to the 4 Topics, and the Data section, of the event logs.

Topic 0 receives the FUNCTIONHASHES that are shown in Solidity, but I am not clear how the other 3 Topics, and the Data section, are assigned.

For example, the following function uses the **note** modifier, which emits the event log. Where in the event log will the values of '**what**' and '**data**' be placed, and what is placed in the Data section of the event log?

```
function file(bytes32 what, uint256 data) external note {
    require(live == 1, "Pot/not-live");
    require(now == rho, "Pot/rho-not-updated");
    if (what == "dsr") dsr = data;
    else revert("Pot/file-unrecognized-param");
}
```

**This contract emits the event logs:**

```
contract LibNote {
    event LogNote(
        bytes4   indexed  sig,
        address  indexed  usr,
        bytes32  indexed  arg1,
        bytes32  indexed  arg2,
        bytes             data
    ) anonymous;

    modifier note {
    _;
    assembly {
        // log an 'anonymous' event with a constant 6 words of calldata
        // and four indexed topics: selector, caller, arg1 and arg2
        let mark := msize                         // end of memory ensures zero
        mstore(0x40, add(mark, 288))              // update free memory pointer
        mstore(mark, 0x20)                        // bytes type data offset
        mstore(add(mark, 0x20), 224)              // bytes size (padded)
        calldatacopy(add(mark, 0x40), 0, 224)     // bytes payload
        log4(mark, 288,                           // calldata
             shl(224, shr(224, calldataload(0))), // msg.sig
             caller,                              // msg.sender
             calldataload(4),                     // arg1
             calldataload(36)                     // arg2
            )
       }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using remix.ethereum.org, here is an example that can help.

[image]

The `input`, which is the same as `calldata`, is `0x29ae811475944220b52381f169021a7c3f2947dfd0d2b1fb95e6cd92358e0a7997c8a9a1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f`.
(This is calling `file( 0x75944220b52381f169021a7c3f2947dfd0d2b1fb95e6cd92358e0a7997c8a9a1, 15)`)

`calldataload` is the EVM opcode for getting 32 bytes from `calldata`.

The parameter to `calldataload` is an offset: typically the first 4 bytes of `calldata` is a function selector, so `calldataload(4)` is used to get the 32 bytes starting from the fifth byte (in this example, `0x75944...`).

`calldata(36)` then gets the next 32 bytes, which is 15 in hex, padding the `uint` to 32 bytes, that's how it becomes `0x000...f`.

See [What is calldata?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52989/what-is-calldata) and [How calldata is stored in memory?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/59119/how-calldata-is-stored-in-memory) for other examples of `calldata`.

The logs are:

```
[
    {
        "from": "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a",
        "data": "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",
        "topics": [
            "0x29ae811400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "0x000000000000000000000000ca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c",
            "0x75944220b52381f169021a7c3f2947dfd0d2b1fb95e6cd92358e0a7997c8a9a1",
            "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f"
        ]
    }
]
```

The last two topics are the `what` and `data` arguments of `file`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Two additional questions:
1. Is Topic 1 the Ethereum Address of the person who called the function?
2. What is placed in the Data section of the event log?

Comment: 1. Yes (topics[1] ca35b... is msg.sender).   2. With the code it looks like 0x20 and 244 (which is 0xe0) is logged as the first bytes of the log data, then the calldata, and a whole bunch of zeroes: you should try to contact whoever wrote the contract for why and further explanations.